# How to move only specific blocks of XML to a new XML file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to filter an XML such that only specific blocks of XML would be needed
I have the original XML like this

```
<PROJECT>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 1" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 2" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 3" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 4" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
</PROJECT>
```

Now I need to compare `<INSTALL_METHOD installer="x" />` and move the entire **TASK** block to a new file, so for example, if I want only TYPE 1 and TYPE 3 the `new.xml` should look something like this

```
<PROJECT>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 1" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
<TASK>
    <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 3" />
    <FILE>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
        <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
    </FILE>
</TASK>
</PROJECT>
```

I tried the below approach to locate the  based on the installer type but I'm getting only the attribute, not able to get the subelements/children of this tag.

```
root = tree.getroot()
tasklist = root.find("TASK")
blocktype = root.findall(".//TASK/INSTALL_METHOD")
filelist = root.findall(".//TASK/FIND)
if blockType.text == "TYPE 1":
    for tasks in filelist:
         installer.getchildren()
tree.write("new.xml", encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: `root.findall(".//TASK/FIND)` has a syntax error (missing end quote) and it attempts to locate `FIND` elements. There are no such elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `TASK`, check the value of the `installer` attribute on the `INSTALL_METHOD` child element. Remove the `TASK`s for which the value is not "TYPE 1"  or "TYPE 3".

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tasks = root.findall("TASK")
   
for task in tasks:
    install_method = task.find("INSTALL_METHOD")
    if not install_method.get("installer") in ["TYPE 1" , "TYPE 3"]:
        root.remove(task)

tree.write("new.xml", encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Thank You!!so much for the answer. Just one query, what if TASK tag would be nested inside outer BLOCK tags. Something like <PROJECT><BLOCK> The above xml</BLOCK></PROJECT>. Would `root.remove(task)` would still work?

Comment: You need to run `remove()` on the parent element. With `BLOCK` added the root element is no longer the parent of `TASK`.

Comment: Something like this? `tasks = root.findall(".//BLOCK/TASK")` `for task in tasks:root.remove(task)`

Comment: If you need more help, please ask a new question.

Comment: I'll do it now, thanks!

Comment: Could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206706/how-to-add-remove-only-specific-blocks-of-xml-to-a-new-file