# How to add/remove only specific blocks of XML to a new file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, file-copying

I'm trying to filter an XML such that only specific blocks of XML would be needed I have the original XML like this

```
<PROJECT>
  <BLOCKLIST>
      <BLOCK>
        <TASK>
            <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 1" />
            <FILE>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
            </FILE>
        </TASK>
        <TASK>
             <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 2" />
             <FILE>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
             </FILE>
         </TASK>
         <TASK>
            <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 3" />
            <FILE>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
            </FILE>
        </TASK>
        <TASK>
            <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 4" />
            <FILE>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
            </FILE>
        </TASK>
    </BLOCK>
  </BLOCKLIST>
</PROJECT>
```

Now I need to compare <INSTALL_METHOD installer="x" /> and move the entire TASK block to a new file , so for example, if I want only TYPE 1 and TYPE 3 the new.xml should look something like this

```
<PROJECT>
<BLOCKLIST>
    <BLOCK>
      <TASK>
        <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 1" />
        <FILE>
            <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
            <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
        </FILE>
      </TASK>
      <TASK>
        <INSTALL_METHOD installer="TYPE 3" />
        <FILE>
            <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="signature"/>
            <INSTALL_OPTIONS option="checksum"/>
        </FILE>
      </TASK>
    </BLOCK>
</BLOCKLIST>
</PROJECT>
```

I tried the below approach, but I'm getting the following error **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list**.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tasks = root.findall(".//BLOCKLIST/BLOCK/TASK")
   
for task in tasks:
    install_method = task.find("INSTALL_METHOD")
    if not install_method.get("installer") in ["TYPE 1" , "TYPE 3"]:
        root.remove(task)

tree.write("new.xml", encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is not a direct child of `root`, so you can't remove it like this. If you use `lxml.etree` instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree` you can get the `task` parent and use it to remove the task (the rest of the code is without change)

```
import lxml.etree as ET

...
if not install_method.get("installer") in ["TYPE 1", "TYPE 3"]:
    task.getparent().remove(task)
...
```